# Prototype and this: toString-method returns instead of object, why? Coercion?

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, coercion

When I run this code:

```
const foo = function() { return this };
class Foo { toString() { return 'Tjo'}};
const obj = new Foo();
Foo.prototype.foo = foo;
console.log('C = ' + obj.foo());
console.log(obj.foo());
```

I expect to get the Foo-object but instead I get:

```
C = Tjo
Foo {}
```

Why do I get the 'Tjo' inside my toString-method?

Comment: Because `obj.foo()` returns an object with a `toString` method which is then used in a string context.

Comment: Because you are doing `'C = ' + `, which coerces the second operand to a string